# In Bitrix how can I set a custom field of type list in a lead in PHP?

Tags: php, bitrix

I can set numbers and string from form subissions but I cannot figure out how to set a a value to a Data type list. I have a number of possible values available in the list but don't know how to set any of them. Could someone link to a tutorial or an example that demonstrates how to do this?

Unfortunately I don't speak Russian and most help resources seem to be in that language.

**Data type (only for new field):** List
**Entity:** CRM_LEAD_SPD
**Field ID (only for new field):**  UF_CRM_5F1A26014BECB

ID  XML_ID  Value   Sort.

623
407b227030a3c23c91022b233078c77b
PCB
10

624
1adb2467f6ecb3519495e9f117829059
PCB (PCB and Assembly)
20

625
aab56fa9638f6f2b45de957dce4f4791
Assembly (PCB and Assembly)
30

626
406933e29d56304d36484428ba299413
Design
40

627
44c2674af0a69a99c91baa34690772a5
Bring Up

This all works except for the list under **UF_CRM_5F1A26014BECB**

```
$arLead = [

 'TITLE' => 'NEW ORDER',
 'SOURCE_ID' => 'WEBFORM',
 'NAME'  => $name,
'UF_CRM_5F1A26014BECB' => 'PCB',
 'LAST_NAME' => $last_name,
 'COMPANY_TITLE' => $company_name,
 'FM' => array("EMAIL" => array("n0" => array('VALUE' => $email, 'VALUE_TYPE' => 'WORK'))),
 'COMMENTS' => $comment,
 'UF_CRM_1582198042398' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'prev_order'),
 'UF_CRM_1540488601233' => $lead_time

];
```

Answer (score 0):

For future readers:

To set the list item you need to first find the desired entry id:

**623** 407b227030a3c23c91022b233078c77b PCB 10

Then set with:

```
$arLead = [

  'UF_CRM_1589478135591' => "623"

];
```

I found this by crawling through a Russian forum and liberal use of Google translate,